# STD on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, std

So I keep running into problems with C++ WP Development. I compiled the code, but VS can't send it to my device saying something like `Cannot deploy application. Invalid XAP package or WP manifest signature` (sorry for poor translation).

I ran Market Tests and got following errors:
`cannot use machine API MSVCP110D.dll?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ()`
`cannot use machine API MSVCP110D.dll?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z()`
and so on, I got plenty of those. As I presume from the name, it has something to do with STD, wich is simply crazy - do MS forbid me to use STD?

Any ideas what that can be and how can I fix that?

**EDIT:** it basically complains about using those 4 libs: `MSVCP110D.dll vccorlib110d.dll MSVCR110D.dll api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll` maybe that'll help.

**EDIT2:** i rebuilt everything I could with release, and now most errors are gone, but I still have these:
`api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll:GetModuleFileNameW()`
`api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll:LoadLibraryExW()`

I think I'm close to finding this stuff out, I heeared that those things are forbidden on WP, gotta search what library is using them.

Comment: WP 7.X forbids native development or your post about 8.X?

Comment: @Alexander my post is about 8.X, 8.0 to be exact.

Comment: The cert errors are from the debug build. You can use retail std C libraries. That's not related to problems deploying the test app. Debug builds are expected for testing. Check that the manifest is valid, do a clean build to make sure the xap isn't corrupt, make sure you're building for ARM, etc. My guess is you're building x86 (for emulator) not ARM (for device)

Comment: @RobCaplan-MSFT I tried compiling both for "Release" and "Debug", but it did not help. I rebuilt it hundreds of times and nothing works. Tried ARM and x86. I'll do some more tests to provide some additional info if there'd be any.

Answer (score 1):

The error could be in your project settings, or in your SDK installation.

Ensure Platform Toolset = Windows Phone 8.0 (v110)
Ensure Library directories = $(WP80ToolSetPath)lib\arm;$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_ARM); (or the corresponding x86)
Ensure you have WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP define in the project properties

And (my favorite one) if you're linking with some non-framework static libraries, or non-framework DLLs, ensure they all were built with the same settings, PLUS their "runtime library" settings match that of your main project.

If everything's correct, then my #2 suspect is SDK installation. Try compiling same source on different machine (e.g. on a virtual one).

Comment: I edited the question to actually answer your answer ^_^